# Infinite loop after combine two linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I have two linked list `Target` and `List`

```
      struct node
        {
            int data;
            struct node *next;
        };

        struct snode
        {
            struct node *head;
            struct node *last;
            int size;
        };
void *createlist(struct snode *list)
{
    list->head = NULL;
    list->last = NULL;
    list->size = 0;
}


struct node *createnode(int data)
{
    struct node *temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    return temp;
}

int Add(struct snode *list, int data, int pos) 
{
    struct node *temp = createnode(data);
    if (pos == 0) // add to first node
    {
        if (list->head == NULL)
        {
            list->head = temp;
            list->last = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->next = list->head;
            list->head = temp;
        }
    }
    else if (pos == -1) // add to last node
    {
        if (list->head == NULL)
            list->head = temp;
        else
        {
            struct node *pre = list->head;
            while (pre->next != NULL)
                pre = pre->next;
            pre->next = temp;
            temp->next = NULL;
        }
    }
    else // add to the middle
    {
        int k = 1;
        struct node *pre = list->head;
        while ((pre != NULL) && (k != pos))
        {
            pre = pre->next;
            k++;
        }
        if ((k != pos) || (pos > list->size))
            return 0;
        else
        {
            temp->next = pre->next;
            pre->next = temp;
        }
    }
    list->size++;
    return 1;;
}
int copy(struct snode *target, struct snode *list)
{
    struct node *temp1 = list->head;
    struct node *temp2 = createnode(temp1->data);
    target->head = temp2;
    if (temp1 == NULL)
        return 0;
    while (temp1 != NULL)
    {
        temp2->next = temp1->next;
        temp1 = temp1->next;
        temp2 = temp2->next;
        target->size++;
    }
    return 1;
}
void printlist(struct snode list)
{
    while (list.head != NULL)
    {
        printf("%2d", list.head->data);
        list.head = list.head->next;
    }
}
int main()
{
    struct snode list;
    struct snode target;
    createlist(&list);
    createlist(&target); //create empty linkedlist
    Add(&list, 4, 0); //add node to linkedlist
    Add(&list, 6, 1);
    Add(&list, 9, -1);
    Add(&list, 7, 2);
    Add(&list, 5, 3);
    copy(&target,&list); //copy list to target
    combine(&target,&list);
    printlist(target);
}
```

I wanted to connect `Target` with `List` so i used this function

```
void combine(struct snode *target, struct snode *list)
{
    struct node *temp1=list->head;
    struct node *temp2=target->head;
    while(temp2->next!=NULL)
        temp2=temp2->next;
    temp2->next = list->head;

}
```

But when i print it,it creates infinite loop. I tried to debug and I saw that after this line:

```
temp2->next = list->head
```

the last node of `List` point to the first node of `List`.

I don't know why this happened,can someone tell me why and how to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you add just enough of `main` and test data to create a [mcve], please?

Comment: You still need to add at the end `target->last= list->last;`

Comment: We also need to see createlist and Add to understand if the link list you built is OK.

Comment: Post complete code.

Comment: sorry,i just edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get an infinite loop from the code you've posted, but I can easily see how that would happen. The problem is the combination of copy and combine: copy makes it so that target only differs in in head, but all the nodes after that are the exact same as in list. So when you iterate through target in combine, and then set the last node's next to list's head you've created a loop.

I don't know exactly what your intention is, but one way of solving this is to only copy the node data in copy, not the whole node pointer.